# Rails ActiveRecord method save! saves data but there is no record in db

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I am a very confused. I have code which stores data in the database succesfully, then I start a Sidekiq job, and first line is to select that record, but it fails on error `RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Message with 'id'=5789035)`

Here is the code:

```
message = Message.new(
  user: user,
  from: from,
  content: content,
  kind: kind
)

message.save!
```

Until now, everything is absolutely ok, save returns object with ID, but then I kick out the job.

```
SendMessage.perform_later(message_id: message.id) if message
```

The code of `SendMessage` fails on the first line, which is `message = Message.find(args.first[:message_id])`

And fails on error `RecordNotFound (Couldn't find Message with 'id'=5789035)` and there is no record in the database with this id.

I don't understand why method `save` didn't fail or so, or why the record is missing. It happens just sometimes, I cannot find the case. But yes can be anything, but why method save behaves like this?

I am logging message object after calling `save!` method with ID, and there is data including ID inside.

When I that case repeat on console, it is successfully repeated.

These failures are around 10 - 50 per month and successful savings are around 2 thousand.

The database is set correctly

Please do you have any suggestions?

Comment: There could be any number of reasons this is happening. Does the `.save!` yield any error? Does the transaction get rolled back? You're using a queue, which makes me think another app is processing the response. Does this app point to the same database? Can you try and save using the same data, in the console, and post the results?

Comment: The `save!` method throws an exception when the object can't be created. It can be due to multiple reasons including your model-level validations or database-level constraints. There is no way that the record is successfully saved and later it vanishes unless there is some code where you are destroying the object.

Comment: Is there any chance these records are somehow deleted / soft_deleted?

Answer (score 0):

It could be caused by a cached DB which is a bit common in ActiveJobs

try:

```rb
Message.uncached do
  message = Message.find(args.first[:message_id])
  # rest of the block
end
```

alternately `ActiveJob` now [uses the new `Globalid` library](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html#globalid) behind the scenes to serialize/deserialize an ActiveRecord instance, therefore you can now pass an `ActiveRecord` object.

```rb
SendMessage.perform_later(message: message) if message
```